# How to include multiple await calls in MobX action

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mobx

I'm working on an app that requires multiple calls using the `await` syntax inside a MobX action. A typical example looks like this:

```
  @action.bound
  async mintToken() {
    const tokenInstance = await this.token.deployed();    
    await tokenInstance.mint(1, { from: this.account });
    await this.updateLastMintedToken();
    await this.updateTokenDetails();
  }
```

However, this code doesn't seem to execute correctly, due to the way MobX handles actions. According to the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html#async-await):

> @action only applies to the code block until the first await. And
>   after each await a new asynchronous function is started, so after each
>   await, state modifying code should be wrapped as action.

The example given in the docs uses `runAsAction`, which I attempted in the following code:

```
  @action.bound
  async updateLastMintedToken() {
    const tokenInstance = await this.token.deployed();

    runInAction(async function() {
      const result = await tokenInstance.lastTokenMinted.call();
      this.lastTokenMinted = result.toNumber();
    });

  }
```

Unfortunately this didn't work, because `this` becomes undefined inside the `runInAction` call so I can't mutate the state.

Any direction in running multiple async calls in an action is very appreciated!

Comment: _"Unfortunately this didn't work, because this becomes undefined inside the runInAction call so I can't mutate the state"_ Have you tried using arrow function for `runInAction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrow function to set the context within `runInAction` to the same context as `updateLastMintedToken` function

```
  @action.bound
  async updateLastMintedToken() {
    const tokenInstance = await this.token.deployed();

    runInAction(async () => {
      const result = await tokenInstance.lastTokenMinted.call();
      this.lastTokenMinted = result.toNumber();
    });

  }
```

Comment: `function runInAction(fn) {
    fn()
}

const o = {
abc:123,
updateLastMintedToken() {
    runInAction(async () => {console.log(this)})
  }
}; o.updateLastMintedToken()`